# check if value is available in DB or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery

I have a table which has the schema:

```
id   |  name 
1    | AD
2    | BC
```

i need a query for the report which contains whether the name i give exists in the DB .

```
name | isExists
AD   | yes
BC   | yes
CA   | NO
```

the name AD,BC,CA should be given by me and its not in any other table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join against a values list:

```
select v.name, t.name is not null as does_exist
from (
   values ('AD'), ('BC'), ('CA')
) as v(name)
  left join the_table t on t.name = v.name;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `values()` to generate rows that contain the search values, then `exists` to check whether they exist in the table:

```
select x.name, 
    exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.name = x.name) exists_in_table
from (values ('AD'), ('BC'), ('CA')) x(name)
```

The upside of this approach, as opposed to solutions using `join`s, is that it does not multiply the rows when a name occurs that once in the source table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a left join. For example:

```
with 
params (name) as (
  select 'AD' union all 
  select 'BD' union all 
  select 'CA' 
),
select distinct params.name,
  case when t.name is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as isExists  
from params
left join t on t.name = params.name
```

Comment: this solution can potentially repeat if you have non-unique names in the table t. using a DISTINCT clause will ensure there are no repeats.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Good catch. Fixed.